# Uploading files using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to use a [drag and drop plugin](http://pascalprecht.github.com/DnD.js/) in javascript to upload files using ajax.

```
<script>
DnD.on('#drop-area', {

'drop': function (files, el) {
   el.firstChild.nodeValue = 'Drag some files here.';
   var names = [];
   [].forEach.call(files, function (file, i) {
      names.push(file.name + ' (' + file.size + ' bytes)');

   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open('POST','upload.php');
   xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data"); 
   xhr.send(file);
   console.log(xhr.responseText);
});
document.querySelector('#dropped-files p i').firstChild.nodeValue = names.join(', ');
}
});
</script>
```

And here's upload.php:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Basically I haven't written the script to upload the file yet because I'm still figuring out how can I have access to the data that I've sent through JavaScript. Can you guide me on what to do next? How do I access the file from upload.php.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to use `FormData` instead of `xhr`:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("thefile", file);
xhr.send(formData);
```

You have access to your file with this `array`:

```
<?php var_dump($_FILES["thefile"]); ?>
```

See more: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: I still don't see anything when I console.log(xhr.responseText);

Comment: What's your web browser? Please pay attention that `XMLHttpRequest` don't works in IE.

Comment: I'm using chrome canary. Thanks for all your help but it still wouldn't work seems like no file is being sent at all.

Comment: Do you try to use `FormData` in JavaScript code? Answer edited please check it again

Comment: There's some solutions for debugging this problem. First of all enable your PHP `error_handling` and set it to `E_ALL`, now you may see some errors or warnings.
If this is not helped, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659340/ajax-uploading-a-file-html-5-php
Add `X-File-Type` and `X-File-Name` to your headers (in xhr request) and also fill 3rd argument in `xhr.open` with `true`.

Answer (score 0):

PHP Code :

```
<?php
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
   echo $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
 }
?>
```

HTML Code :

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="file-to-upload" type="file" name="file-to-upload">
    <button id="btn-submit">upload</button>
</form>
```

Javascript Code :

```
document.querySelector('#btn-submit').addEventListener('click' , function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
        /**
         * formData() representing form fields
         * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData
         */
        formData = new FormData(); 
        /**
         * fileToUpload [input file]
         * input file has property called [files] contain 1 or multiple files
         * i use one file so i get 0 index file => image.files[0]
         */
        fileToUpload = document.querySelector('#file-to-upload');
        formData.append('fileToUpload' , fileToUpload.files[0]);
        /**
         * XMLHttpRequest
         */
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST' , 'page.php' , true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(xhr.readyState == 4){
                console.log(this.responseText);
            }
        }
        xhr.send(formData);
    });
```