# Is there any way to get data sent in AJAX again on Submitting form?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, forms, upload

I am using an image uploading library innostudio/fileuploader, in which AJAX is necessary for Drag & Drop Feature, now i don't want to upload images on AJAX but for drag & drop i've made random empty function which creates nothing (not uploading an image). **I want to upload image on form submit, but the issue is i'm getting $_FILES empty if i uses AJAX**, i've tried sending uploaded image in base64 format which causing POST request error. (Request entity Too Large)

Comment: take a look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879841/uploading-files-using-xmlhttprequest

Comment: @Tschitsch i'm getting $_FILES data completely empty on submit

Comment: I've read your question, but have you checked the provided link *and* its answer?

Comment: I've read question and answer given by you, the thing is i understand process of uploading image, i'm getting image data in $_FILES in AJAX function, but after that the data is not available on submit form, is there any possibility of using that library casing an error?

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood your question, sorry for that. Iff you've already successfully uploaded a file you could add a reference (e.g. file_id or serverpath) for that file within your form, a reference to a local file will most likely not work imho.